# Hide page title

Tags: php, pages, title

I have created a custom page template and want to hide page title from the page.

How do I do this? I know I can just leave page title blank or do it in CSS and that works but isn't that bad for SEO etc? How do I write the conditional statement and where do I put it?

Here is my template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: No Title Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It's impossible to say since this `get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );` is loading another template file that you have not showed us.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple:

Don't forget to move `add_filter` to functions.php file :)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: No Title Page
*/ 
add_filter( 'the_title', function ($title) { return "";});
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind what you've done but perhaps you could explain it?

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! That worked like a charm! I did however have to move that line down under the get header otherwise it was hiding my menu. Otherwise PERFECT! Thanks again!

Comment: @oOPurple_HazeOo welcome :)

Comment: `create_function` Really?

Comment: @PieterGoosen Why no ? :)

Comment: [user defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: Also see the php manual on anonomous functions :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen you can also you like:
`add_filter( 'the_title', return create_function('', 'return "";'));`

Comment: Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php). You should **NEVER** use `create_function`. It is really up to you, but keep in mind, it is totally **wrong**. According to the amount of downvotes your answer has recieved...

Comment: @PieterGoosen please explain this. Most developers use this type widely at WordPress plugins and Theme development. See Codex – http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter . The only thing, that it's bad for caching and APC optimisers.

Comment: Yes, your use of the filter is correct to filter `the_title`. You can make use of [lambda functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) PHP 5.3+. What is wrong is `create_function()`. You should **only** use `function()`. Any developer still making use of `create_function()` should go back to school. It poses one big security risk, and is the cause of many hacked sites.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if your code works, but your second block of code is the correct use. `add_filter( 'the_title', function ($title) { return "";});` is the proper use of anonymous functions (lambda functions). You first block of code is totally wrong

Comment: @PieterGoosen deal ! :)

Comment: Just a tip, if you add code, always give a brief description about how your code works. I have tested your code, and it works. Have upvoted your answer. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your NO TITLE page is calling function

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
```

Which means its calling page 'content-page.php'

I won't recommended to edit this page directly as it might be used at other places in theme.

Solution:

Copy content-page.php and name it content-notitle.php

The remove title from new copied page.

Now you can call this function in your 'No Title Page' custom template like this

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'notitle' );
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your `get_template_part()` you can find `the_title()` function that prints page title.

Simple comment it out or delete it, but never, NEVER use `display:none` with CSS.

Answer (score -3):

Page title can be used in the following code:

```
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="title-header">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

If you'd like to hide it use you can hide it with CSS or comment it out.

CSS:

```
h1.title-header{
   display: none;
}
```

Hiding the element with CSS search engines read the page title even though it doesn't appear on the page.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Please do not roll back my changes. I have properly formatted your code already. Just a tip, if you add code to a post, highlight it in the editor and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will add your code in a code block